# Too big window buttons!

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, themes

I have elementary os loki installed. I've installed a mac os theme, as i like how it does look and changed the layout of the buttons to mac os from the settings. Now, for some reasons, i have some really big buttons here and there in the tilte bar. Take a look:
[image]

See the big search buttons? Same situation for the extract button in the archive manager... Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a GTK theme that's not created for elementary OS.

The only way to fix this is to change back the GTK theme to the default theme (or one that does support elementary OS), or to ask the creator of the theme if he/she wants to add support for elementary OS.

Comment: OK, i figured out... it was the icon pack that was off...thanks for the answer